# AutoMapper graceful handling of NULL

Tags: automapper

I'm mapping a pretty deeply nested entity to a flattened `Dto` object and was wondering how  I'd handle this gracefully with AutoMapper.  I know I could null check each property as it's being mapped, but that's going to get VERY ugly for things like:

```
ForMember(s => s.Property, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Parent.Child1.Child2.Child3.Property)
```

So I'm guess I could use various maps configs to the same destination object... but being relatively unskilled with AutoMapper I'm not sure what the performance implications of this are.  What other, better, ways do I have of achieving what I want?

To re-iterate, I'm *hoping* to avoid something like this (I'm aware the below code probably doesn't compile... it's just an example) which I'd have to do for **every** member:

```
ForMember(s => s.Property, o => o.MapFrom(
    s => s.Parent == null ? string.Empty :
    s => s.Parent.Child1 == null ? string.Empty :
    s => s.Parent.Child1.Child2 == null ? string.Empty :
    s => s.Parent.Child1.Child2.Child3 == null ? string.Empty :
    s => s.Parent.Child1.Child2.Child3.Property));
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think AutoMapper will actually handle `null` propagation like this automatically for you. Your example:

```
ForMember(s => s.Property, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Parent.Child1.Child2.Child3.Property)
```

should resolve to `null`(I *think*), if any of the intermediate members are `null`.

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/hMo3wa

Comment: That's interesting if it works... really didn't expect it.  I'll give it a shot - how do you think it'll handle lazy loaded properties in this way?

Comment: You're absolutely right!  Didn't expect this, but I'm happy it works.  Thanks!

Comment: if, like me you need to do something more complex like a Math.Max of some field and you want to have defaults, creating a static method seems to work too as such:


ForMember(s => s.Property, o => o.MapFrom(s => CustomFunction(s))

Comment: This mostly works for me, and I use it for null coalescing, but it doesn't seem to work (for me) for instances where the children are lists and using FirstOrDefault e.g. s => s.Parent.Child1.FirstOrDefault().Property ?? "some default". I can see how it fails outside of the automapper because accessing "Property" of null will break, but in the automapper is seems to ignore the null coalescing and just return null. Why would that be the case?

Comment: @JarrodMcGuire I'm not sure why your coalesced value is null, but an alternative approach might be to use the NullSubstitute option, e.g. `opt.MapFrom(s => s.Parent.Child1.FirstOrDefault().Property); opt.NullSubstitute("some default")`, or event the `NullSubstituteAttribute`

Answer (score 2):

While this works for individual instances, it does not work for Projections on queryable collections.

This additional code I added to Andrew's answer fails miserably, even on the latest, 5.1.1 version.

```
    var list = new List<Source>();
    list.Add(new Source());     
    list.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<Dest>().Dump();
```

**Example** https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ecovrp

Comment: This should not be an answer to the question, but rather a comment to Andrew's answer.